# getting image color information from both RGB32 and indexed type images

Tags: image, qt, colors, pixel, scanline

I am trying to access the image colors in a QImage.

The method that I found most in docs is based on the scanline function...

I tried and it worked... on RGB32 images. I had surprising - and unpleasant results when using the exact method to get color data for 8 bit indexed or monochrome images.

This was my code:

```
// note RGBTriple is a struct containing unsigned R, G, B
// rgbImage.pixels is a RGBTriple* array

RGBTriple* pTriple = rgbImage.pixels;
for (int y = 0; y < source.height(); y++)
{
    const unsigned char* pScanLine = source.scanLine(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < source.width(); x++)
    {
         QRgb* color = (QRgb*)pScanLine;
         pTriple->R = qRed(*color);
         pTriple->G = qGreen(*color);
         pTriple->B = qBlue(*color);
         ++pTriple;
         pScanLine += 4;
    }
}
```

Running the same code with images 8bit indexed or monochrome, I got errors in creating getting colors. The documentation says that scanline is aligned to multiples of 32b - but since that is a multiple of 8 and 2 I didn't think it would be a problem.

Once I found out that I am not getting correct results for all types of input images, I changed it to

```
RGBTriple* pTriple = rgbImage.pixels;
for (int y = 0; y < source.height(); y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < source.width(); x++)
    {
        pTriple->R = qRed(source.pixel(x, y));
        pTriple->G = qGreen(source.pixel(x, y));
        pTriple->B = qBlue(source.pixel(x, y));
        ++pTriple;
    }
}
```

Works perfectly... I wonder if it is slower or will have other unexpected behavior ? After all, I am using the pixel() function - even on indexed images - to get color information, which actually should be stored differently... that seems like it should fail...

Is there a way to make the first version, using scanline, work for other image types ?

Why does it seem like using scanline to get the data is the preferred method ?

Comment: About "slower", at least call `pixel` just once and store return Value to a temp variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried and it worked... on RGB32 images. I had surprising - and
>   unpleasant results when using the exact method to get color data for 8
>   bit indexed or monochrome images.

You should not be surprised because the indexed and monochrome images are ***different formats***. The first code snippet you posted is based on the knowledge on how `RGB32` (and `RGB32` only) is layed out in memory.

Think about it. In a monochrome image `R=G=B`. So only one channel need to be saved in memory.

If your goal is to obtain an rgb image inside `rgbImage.pixels` use [QImage::convertToFormat()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#convertToFormat) :

```
QImage source;
QImage dest =  source.convertToFormat( QImage::Format_RGB888 );
memcpy(rgbImage.pixels, dest.bits(),dest.byteCount () );
```

Comment: what will be the contents of rgbImage.pixels ? Will it become am array of unsigned char* with one char for each color - so 3 times the byteCount for size ?

Comment: Yes, it is an arrawy rgbrgbrgb.... where each color is an unsigned char. dest.byteCount for rgb24 is already 3 * width * height byte long. And I would expect rgbImage.pixels to be the same size.